# Touch screen sensitivity

Tags: java, android, touch

I'm developing and testing my libGDX game using Samsung Galaxy S2. The game is currently very simple with just a render loop that checks for input.justTouched(). Since it should be a shooter game, I need ability to shoot bullets quickly.

When I'm testing with device plugged into computer's USB port, everything works fine. I'm getting ~60fps and I can fire 10 shots per second or so. However, when I unplug the USB, the framerate remains the same, but the sensitivity drops, and I can only fire 1-2 shots per second.

I realized it does work if I apply much more pressure while tapping, but it will get tiresome quickly if you play a shooter game like that.

Does Android provide some API to control touch-screen sensitivity?

Comment: You might find [this link (markers-for-android)](https://code.google.com/p/markers-for-android/) helpful.  I'm not sure if Android supports this formally.  Also: a question that deals with this issue: [(How well supported is pressure sensitivity across Android devices?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871685/how-well-supported-is-pressure-sensitivity-across-android-devices)

Answer (score 1):

This answer describes how you can get the pressure properties of a touch event:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716616/2518095

That's not gonna solve your problem, but I think it's a good place to start.  I'd do some testing with your phone plugged in and unplugged to see if those pressure values are actually changing or not.  If they are, maybe you could dive further into the problem armed with that info at least.

Comment: Thanks. I'm off to sleep now, but I'll test it tomorrow.